# Ввод-вывод данных в TurboPascal

Tags: pascal, поток-ввода, связь, turbopascal

Задача - 
Дана программа - имитатор пульта некой системы. Там есть окна ввода информации и окна выдачи информации. Программа работает под MsDos. 
Программа состоит из двух рабочих окон (так как в реальной системе два так называемых ИнПУ - Интегрированных Пульта Управления). По сути они общаются по COM портам. Сами ИнПУ общаются между собой по RS232 по COM1, а информация на них из системы СПС (Система Преобразования Сигналов) подается по COM2.

Хочу реализовать работу этих двух программ на одном ПК посредством или динамической библиотеки или записи в файл. Подскажите как можно это реализовать? Программы должны проверять друг друга, что бы у них было одинаковое время, некоторые параметры  сигнализаторы. Программы написаны на turboPascal.

Comment: У вас есть исходники этих программ, вы их можете модифицировать? Вариант с двумя виртуалками/DOSBox на 1 компе не подходит?

Comment: Исходники есть, но два досбокса не будут работать вместе на одном порту, а я никак не могу разобраться в 200 000 строчек кода что бы сменить СОМ1 на СОМ2.